# Using an ES6 module in both an app and in Node, while using Webpack-Dev-Middleware and Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, babeljs, webpack-dev-middleware

#### Background

Let's say you have an ES2015/ES6 component with a single function as a default export:

> **component.js**

```
export default function() {
    console.log("Hello, World!");
}
```

An app to include it in:

> **app.js**

```
import myComponent from "./component"

myComponent();
```

And an Node.js/Express server using [webpack-dev-middleware](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-middleware), to run Webpack (with Babel) on and serve `app.js`, and to *also* include `component.js` in:

> **server.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

// start the server
app.listen(process.env.EXPRESS_PORT, () => {
    console.log(`App listening on port ${process.env.EXPRESS_PORT}!`);
});

const webpack = require("webpack");
const webpackConfig = require("./webpack.config");
const compiler = webpack(webpackConfig);

// use webpack-dev-middleware to serve the publicPath
app.use(
    require("webpack-dev-middleware")(compiler, {
        logLevel: "warn",
        publicPath: webpackConfig.output.publicPath,
    })
);

// use webpack-hot-middleware for HMR
app.use(require("webpack-hot-middleware")(compiler));

const myComponent = require("./component") // import the component
myComponent(); // use the component
```

#### Question

How might you go about using `component.js` in both `server.js`, as well as in the webpacked `app.js`?

#### Problem

As-is, that component works fine in `app.js`, but throws a `SyntaxError: Unexpected token export` in the Node console when trying to do `const component = require("./component")`.

Since Babel is only running via Webpack, and `server.js` is accessing `component.js` via the original component and not the bundled/transpiled one, we get the error.

I suppose a solution would be to run Babel twice: once on the component before the `server.js` is started, and once again in Webpack, but that seems very inelegant and inefficient.

Comment: Sounds like maybe you should create a third library that is compiled with your component, then import the compiled library into both your server-side and client-side code.

Comment: To use ES6 Modules on node, you need to use the `--experimental-modules` flag and name the files with `.mjs`, see: https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html

Comment: @GabrielCarneiro, sorry, I should have been more clear; I'd rather avoid using experimental features unless they are legitimately the best option. This problem seems like it should be solvable without needing to resort to that.

I also don't necessarily want to import an ES6 module into Node; I want to convert and import it as a CommonJS into Node, while also leaving it alone so it can be imported as an ES6 module elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I seem to have stumbled across a working solution: write the module in CommonJS format, and Webpack/Babel will compile it for ES6.

Working files:

> **component.js**

```
function myComponent() {
    console.log("Hello, World!");
}

module.exports = { myComponent };
```

> **app.js**

```
import myComponent from "./component"

myComponent();
```

> **server.js**

```
const { myComponent } = require("./component") // import the component

myComponent(); // use the component
```